# Hibernate and database

Tags: hibernate

i have recently started working on hibernate.. i wanted to ask that if iam using mysql as backend and hibernate for orm and i have some stored procedures and triggers stored in my mysql db... if i change my backend db to other db like db2 or something else then what will happen to the stored procedures and triggers that are stored in the database... do i need to write them again in db2 .. but this is then not efficient if they are too long ... it would be very helpful if i u all help me :)

Comment: How could a stored procedure written in a now disappeared MySQL database work in a new DB2 database? Black magic? Of course you'll have to migrate them to DB2. That doesn't have anything to do with Hibernate, BTW. Hibernate isn't used to write stored procedures, and doesn't run inside the database like stored procs do.

Comment: i know hibernate is just used for mapping objects but we can call stored procedure with hibernate ... what can i do to avoid rewriting all these again

Comment: one more thing. if i use triggers and it includes a huge code then hw will i migrate it do another db

Comment: The answer is manually.

Answer (score 0):

Hibernate will take care of java side codes always. But we can not do anything with db oriented script and we can not handle it with hibernate. So you should write separate script for migration DB. If you are using hibernate try to avoid server side script.